# How to insert value in Joomla1.5 own created Module

Tags: joomla, module, joomla1.5

I am new in Joomla , i want to insert value by my own module in database in my own table   my module helper class look like

```
// no direct access defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); 
class modmyModuleHelper 
{ 
   function getHello($params)
   {         
       echo $track_code=$_REQUEST['track_code'];
       $sql="insert into jos_ trackno values($track_code)";
       mysql_query($sql);
       $x="<form>Enter Code<input type='text' name='track_code'>
       <input type='submit' name='go' value='GO'></form>";

       //return $sql;           
       return $x; 
   }    
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`. Please refer to the Joomla Documentation on how to write database queries: http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Can you advise what is not working or what is stopping you to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would not name function for inserting to database `getHello`, but rather `insertHello`.

Secondly, use inserting function for this purpose only, don't return some HTML code. Return boolean value and decide later what to display.

I would use something like this:

```
class modmyModuleHelper {

    function insertTrackCode() {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['track_code'])) {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query
                ->insert($db->quoteName('#__trackno'))
                ->values($_REQUEST['track_code']);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            return $db->query();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```